# Why counter is not working after one interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I want to create a time down counter. I already created a counter but it is not working properly and how to reset animation of CSS after one interval.

There is the link of the jsfiddle: `[https://jsfiddle.net/waleedGRT/x4rcj068/10/](https://jsfiddle.net/waleedGRT/x4rcj068/10/)`

Thanks You in advance.

Comment: With all due respect sir, The JSfiddle link isn't working any more. Please share an updated link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exact functionality you're looking for, but this should get you past your problem. **EDIT** updated code as per OP response.

```js
function counterA(valuea) {
  var tempA = valuea;
  setInterval(function() {
    if (tempA < 1) {
      window.history.go(0);
    }
    $('#time').text(tempA);
    tempA--;
  }, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  counterA(11);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative
}

.right {
  border: #3f85a3 solid 15px;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 120px;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  animation: rota2 12000ms linear;
  -moz-animation: rota2 12000ms linear;
  -o-animation: rota2 12000ms linear;
  -webkit-animation: rota2 12000ms linear;
}

@keyframes rota2 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(-225deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rota2 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(-225deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rota2 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(-225deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rota2 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(-225deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

.left {
  border: #3f85a3 solid 15px;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 120px;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(315deg);
  animation: rota 24000ms linear;
  -o-animation: rota 24000ms linear;
  -moz-animation: rota 24000ms linear;
  -webkit-animation: rota 24000ms linear;
}

@keyframes rota {
  from {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(315deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rota {
  from {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(315deg);
  }
}

@moz-keyframes rota {
  from {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(315deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rota {
  from {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(315deg);
  }
}

.middle {
  color: #0987bc;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}

.popover {
  background: white;
  width: 80px;
  height: 162px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  animation: popover 0ms linear;
}

@keyframes popover {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes popover {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes popover {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes popover {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#time {
  font-size: 30px;
}

#timer {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Round E&D</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="right"></div>
      <div class="left"></div>
      <div class="middle">
        <p id="counter"><br />
          <span id="counter">
              <div>
                <span id="timer">
                  0:<span id="time">12</span>
          </span>
      </div>

      </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="popover"></div>
  </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but i also want circle to animate after each interval.